# how to loop until input is the right length

Tags: python, while-loop, string-length

I'm trying to get the user to enter a password (when making an account for my quiz) and check that the password is over 6 characters. If it isn't, it will loop back and ask the user to try another password. Here's what I've got so far:

```
def password ():
    password = input("enter a password over 6 characters")
    count = 0
    for letter in password:
        count = count + 1
    while count < 6:
        password = input("password too short try again") 

password ()
```

Here's what I get if my password is long enough:

```
enter a password over 6 characters longpassword
```

Here's what I get if my password's too short:

```
enter a password over 6 characters lol
password too short try again lol
password too short try again longpassword
password too short try again
```

It doesn't seem to count the characters after the first time and I don't know why.

Comment: Reset `count` to 0 before reading password again.

Comment: Try to also fix your text. All lower case is not good English syntax :). Your text should be presentable and follow English language Syntax please :).

Comment: ok guys i figured out how to do it!

Answer (score 2):

```
password = ""
while len(password) < 6:
    password = input("....")
```